# Recursive Function Prints Large Unintended Values. Trying to Print Recursive Value Requested by Instructions.l

Tags: java, function, recursion

I am calling this recursive function below:

```
public class formula {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    sierpinski(n);
}

public static void sierpinski(int n) {
    System.out.println(n);
    if (n == 0) {
        return;
    }
    else if (n > 0) {
        sierpinski((n-1));
    }
}
```

}

When I keep the argument as n-1 I understand that it would countdown normally but when I then change the code to

```
sierpinkski(3*(n-1));
```

I have the large values provided below.

```
C:\Users\joseph\Desktop\CS111 - 2020\cs111-a5>java formula.java 2
2
3
6
15
42
123
366
1095
3282
9843
29526
88575
265722
797163
2391486
7174455
21523362
64570083
193710246
581130735
1743392202
935209307
-1489339378
```

Is this because it is constantly multiplying by 3 each time it counts down and grows extremely large until there is a large enough value to get below zero and stop? If so how can I print it out so the values match this:

These are the instructions: Write a recursive function sierpinski() that takes one argument n, prints the value n, and then calls itself three times with the value n-1. The recursion should stop when n becomes 0.

This step is to help draw the full triangle but I want to understand the function before i continue. Thank you for your help and explanations.

```
sierpinksi(0)

sierpinksi(1)
1

sierpinski(2)
2
1
1
1

sierpinksi(3)
3
2 1 1 1
2 1 1 1
2 1 1 1

sierpinksi(4)
4
3 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1
3 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1
3 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1

sierpinksi(5)
5
4 3 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 3 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 3 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1
4 3 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 3 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 3 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1
4 3 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 3 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 3 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1
```

Comment: Just go through the numbers to understand why it grows: you first call `sierpinkski(2)` (here `n == 2`), which prints `2`. Now you do recursion with `sierpinkski(3*(n-1)) == sierpinkski(3*1) == sierpinkski(3)`. Since you've passed in `3`, you have `n == 3`, and the next recursion `sierpinkski(3*(n-1)) == sierpinkski(3*2) == sierpinkski(6)`. Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*...and then calls itself three times with the value n-1...* means you just need to duplicate calls to `sierpinski((n-1))` one after the other 3 times as below:

```
sierpinski((n-1));
sierpinski((n-1));
sierpinski((n-1));
```

or you can call them in a loop

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) sierpinski(n-1);
```

then you will see the pattern you want to see

Comment: is there a different way to do this? like 3 * sierpinski to save myself writing 3 lines and just one. Also, thank you for the answer.

Comment: you cannot multiply a function by a number and expect it to execute 3 times, you could call it 3 times in a loop though as in edited answer.